# Why are annotations in higher-order functions unsupported?

Tags: function, kotlin, higher-order-functions

This is the error I get when using custom annotation in a [higher-order](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) function:

[image: image error]

Is there any way to use annotations in higher-order functions? If not, what would be an alternative solution (apart from using enums)?

This is how my custom annotation looks like:

```
companion object {
   private const val PERMISSION_DENIED = 1
   private const val PROVIDER_DISABLED = 2
   private const val SUCCESS = 3

   @IntDef(PERMISSION_DENIED, PROVIDER_DISABLED, SUCCESS)
   @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
   annotation class PreconditionResult
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround**

There's a workaround which involves functional interfaces (notice the `fun interface` below).

**Note:** Unfortunately, functional interfaces that are defined in kotlin code are only available since the upcoming 1.4 release. You can test it now with `1.4-M1`.

```kotlin
fun interface FulFilled {
    fun execute(@PreconditionResult fulFilled: Int): Unit
}

private fun checkPrecondition(context: Context, fulFilled: Fulfilled) {
}
```

```kotlin
checkPrecondition(context) { fulFilled -> println("Got $fulFilled")}
```

**Possible solution**

I'm not sure if it would achieve what you need to, but it's also possible to drop the argument name from your type definition:

```kotlin
private fun checkPrecondition(context: String, callback: (@PreconditionResult Int) -> Unit) {
```

You'll need to change the target of your annotation to a type:

```kotlin
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
    @Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
    annotation class PreconditionResult
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jakub, I'm gonna give it a try with functional interfaces. The second solution works partially since I want to pass only one of the allowed constants defined in `@IntDef` and if I pass undefined one the compiler doesn't warn me about that